# Writing HTML tags same line, in php cycle

Tags: php, html

I want print links in cycle

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
?>
    <a href="#">a</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Problem is that when I see source, each links are write in new line, I need that every will   same line.

I can make this:

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
    str .= '<a href="#">a</a>';
}
echo $str;
```

and result is what I need, but I like first coding style (say, MVC coding style).
What is solution in first coding style, for writing tags same line ?

Comment: Why does it matter how the HTML looks like? Just curious.

Comment: Thats not MVC coding style :P

Comment: @ Felix Not only source visual

http://jsfiddle.net/CxJy9/

http://jsfiddle.net/CxJy9/1/

Comment: Actually the coding style in the second example is much better for performance, you shouldn't force the parser in and out of PHP mode like the first one does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
    ?><a href="#">a</a><?php
}
?>
```

You need to remove the whitespace.